# Long running API request in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular5, angular2-http

I am using Angular 5! I am using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) for every REST API request to my backend server.

The issue I am facing currently is that a few API requests take longer to execute i.e approximately more than 3 minutes. In such cases execution thread keeps on running on the backend rest server but the Angular calls terminate with `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in browser and Angular throws error.

Is this the default behavior or can change settings in `HttpClient` initialization to wait for the API request to complete and not time out after certain threshold limit?

As suggested : I have tried sending and observing response from both chrome and postman client and both are failing after some time.

Postman fails and gives error as : Could not get Response !

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, have you checked the API with some other tool like Postman?

Comment: No !! But that is my question. How to achieve this with Angular ?

Comment: Option 1) Go to Chrome, open dev tools, click on Network and then do your request. Evaluate the details of the request.
Option 2) Open Postman (it has a Chrome extension version, install it), call your endpoint. If the response takes the same or similar time the problem is in the endpoint, nothing to do with Angular or your frontend. If the answer time is significantly fast then share your code and lets see what is happening.

Comment: Even Postman is throwing error ! Saying could not get Response !

Both chrome and Postman are behaving in same manner

Comment: Then the problem is in the backend because Postman doesn't goes through your Angular ;)